# Show a number of text boxes based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, textbox

I want to display a number of textboxes in a form based on the selected option from a dropdown listbox.

For example, if user selects 1 then 1 textbox should be shown and if user selects 2 then 2 textboxes should be displayed. And I need to do it in PHP.

I found some answers using jQuery. Can we use jQuery inside PHP? If yes, then how?

Edit

@Edwin Alex 
This is how my select option looks like.

```
<h2><u>DEPENDENT DETAILS</u></h2><br />
            <table  border="1" style="border-style:dotted" width="100%" id="dependenttable">
            <tr><td>No of Dependent</td><td><select name="numDep" id="dropdown">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option></select></td></tr>

            <tr id="textboxDiv"></tr>
```

At the end of file inside <> these I have written your code.

Comment: stackoverflow is where you ask questions about specific problems you encounter when you're already coding. while it may be possible to help you this isn't a tutorial site. more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: You want every created input name must be different ?

Comment: yes i want them to be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery to get this. Try this,

HTML :

```
<tr><td>No of Dependent</td><td><select name="numDep" id="dropdown">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option></select></td>
</tr>

<tr id="textboxDiv"></tr>
```

Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown").change(function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        $("#textboxDiv").html('');
        if(selVal > 0) {
            for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
                $("#textboxDiv").append('<input type="text" name="textVal[]" value="" />');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Paste this code at the bottom of your page inside  tag.

Your select box ID should be `dropdown`.

You need to have a div with an ID `textboxDiv` to place your generated textboxes.

Comment: Do i need to call this function anywhere.

Comment: no.. if you define your selectbox id as dropdown. This function will be called when you change the value in the select box.

Comment: it is displaying 3 boxes at unaligned format even before i select a value in select box.

Comment: It won't display text boxes before you select the value. Can you update your post with the code?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. See i have edited with your HTML and full script.

Comment: Thank you.Now it works perfectly.Did not call jquery in script tag.That was the mistake done.I am now changing it to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it easily with the help of JavaScript. Here is an example of it. Try it and modify it according to your requirement

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Select DIV to show</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(obj) {
no = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
count = obj.options.length;
for(i=1;i<count;i++)
document.getElementById('myDiv'+i).style.display = 'none';
if(no>0)
document.getElementById('myDiv'+no).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<select onChange="show(this)">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="myDiv1" style="display:none"> <form>
<select>
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
</form></div>
<div id="myDiv2" style="display:none"><form><input type="text" ><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="submit"/></form></div>
<div id="myDiv3" style="display:none"><form><input type="text" ><br>
<input type="text"/><br>
<input type="submit"/></form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example just change the code in "myDiv1", "myDiv2", "myDiv3". I think it will hep you.:)

Comment: Yes i know javascript is easy.but my requirement is to do it in PHP only.Any way thank for taking time to help.

Comment: You can't do it in PHP only. You have to use javascript and just display the text fields in PHP code.